# How to add product to cart with selected product attributes and selected attribute price?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, e-commerce, cart, inertiajs

I am working on a project with Laravel and inertia react on the front end and i am trying to add a product with attributes. when i add a simple product with no attributes it was added to cart without any problems but when the product has attributes i couldn't figure how i can add the selected attribute and change the price based on the selected attribute.

my form submit function looks like this:

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState({
  qty: 1,
  productID: product.id,
  price: "",
  attributes: [],
});

function handleChange(e) {
  const key = e.target.id;
  const value = e.target.value;
  setValues((values) => ({
    ...values,
    [key]: value,
  }));
}

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Inertia.post(route("tenant.cart.add_to_cart"), values);
}
```

and my form containing the select attributes and quantity input is as follows:

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
    {attributes.map((attribute, index) => (
      <>
        {product.attributes
          .map((s) => s.attribute_id)
          .includes(attribute.id) && (
          <div key={index}>
            <select
              id="attributes"
              onChange={handleChange}
              className="w-full cursor-default bg-white border border-gray-300 py-2.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-left focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
              required
            >
              <option data-price="0" value="">
                Select {attribute.name}
              </option>

              {product.attributes.map((pattr, index) => (
                <>
                  {pattr.attribute_id === attribute.id && (
                    <option
                      className="relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4"
                      key={index}
                      value={pattr.value}
                      data-price={pattr.price}
                    >
                      {pattr.value}
                    </option>
                  )}
                </>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    ))}
  </div>
</form>
```

i tried to get the price by using event dataset to get the data-price attribute but it returns undefined and i dont know how to achieve addind to cart with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I cloned a part of your project. Because you didn't share all codes with us. I have checked the attribute value and I couldn't see any problems according to the following example. I think, your problem is related to your conditions or state value. If you want to examine the example, you can reach this example by using [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-rgb-d4ycjb?file=/src/App.js). Maybe when you examine it, it can be useful to resolve your problem.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    qty: 1,
    productID: 1,
    price: "",
    attributes: []
  });

  function handleChange(e) {
    const key = e.target.id;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setValues((values) => ({
      ...values,
      [key]: value
    }));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(values);
  }, [values]);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
        <div>
          <select
            id="attributes"
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="w-full cursor-default bg-white border border-gray-300 py-2.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-left focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
            required
          >
            <option data-price="0" value="">
              Select
            </option>
            <option
              className="relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4"
              value="13"
              data-price="13"
            >
              13
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: i couldnt get the data-price attribute from the selected option thatwas the problem however i tried to accomplish that task using the backend by finding the product with the given id and check in the attributes, if the selected value matches the attribute then display the price instead of the front end.